# Is any way to put bar inside another bar in bar chart Power BI?

Tags: bar-chart, data-visualization, powerbi

Bar chart represents current year premium vs last year.  looks like this now:
[image]

But I want to put last year premium inside the current year premium bar. 
something like that:

[image]

Is it possible to achieve in Power BI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is *not possible* with the built-in visualizations, currently, but check out the [Bullet Chart custom visual by OKViz](https://web.archive.org/web/20170512195712/https://okviz.com/bullet-chart/).

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.